# Help for `fat finger` on Google Galaxy Nexus

Tags: keyboard

I often have trouble with the on-screen keyboard, e.g. pressing the wrong keys etc.

I looked around and found that [ThickButton](http://androidandme.com/2010/03/news/thickbuttons-launches-keyboard-for-fat-fingers/) looks like a good solution; but sadly it is not compatible with my Galaxy Nexus.

What can I do to get rid of mistyping keys?

Comment: There are any number of alternative keyboards in the Play Store. What have you tried?

Comment: What I tried is the link I put in the word `here` that you have corrected for me

Comment: I think when editing, please make sure your correction is better in grammar and meaning. You changed mine a lot hic

Comment: Not that much, but I did try to make it a question about a problem you're trying to solve instead of just trying to find an app. Edit back anything that I may have gotten wrong.

Comment: If all you've tried is the app you linked to, then my suggestion is: check out the Play Store and try out some of the other keyboards that are available.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the APK of Thumbnail, you can try to sideload it on your Galaxy Nexus.

You can try Swiftkey Keyboard, it works well for me as I have fat fingers too.

Answer (score 1):

[Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) allows you to customize the size of the keyboard up to 3/4s of the screen.  Their suggestions dictionary is also pretty good at deciphering typos.

Alternatively, mash the keyboard with your palm and obtain a [special typing wand](http://handstylus.com/store.html).  ;)

Comment: I have tried `Hacker's Keyboard` as your suggestion but the keyboard UI is not very need to me and ... I don't like it. Thanks anyway!